# ATG browser components is not available

Tags: atg

I want to create new companent in ATG. And if I forward to Browser Companent page, then I have 404 error. How I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are a number of issues that can cause this. So the best way to get help here is to try and post your code, configuration file and perhaps any errors you may have seen in the dynamo.log. We need a bit more information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created a new component by creating a `.properties` file. The things to look for are

- Is the file in an appropriate config layer? i.e. is it in a location on the `configpath`, such as the `config` directory of a module, or the `localconfig` directory of a server, where the application expects to look for `.properties` files?
- Is the file a valid `.properties` file and properly formatted?
- Is the class mentioned in the `$class` property correct, valid and fully qualified (package name and class name)
- Has the named class been compiled successfully?
- Is the named class available on the `classpath`? i.e. is it in the `classes.jar` of a module or in the `classes` directory (if that is how the module's class path has been defined?
- Is the class a valid JavaBean - particularly, does it have a no-argument constructor?
- Have you compiled, built and assembled your ATG application since creating this new component?
- Have you restarted your ATG application since creating this new component?

Assuming this is all correct and yet you still cannot see your component, the next step is to troubleshoot why it is not visible.

- Is the path to your component you are using in the dyn/admin component browser correct?
- If the path is correct, and you still see an error in the browser, then take a look at the server logs (for around the time you first tried to access the component) - you might see an error or a sequence of errors telling you why the server could not instantiate the component
- Can you go to the containing folder and see if the component is listed there - though it is OK if you cannot because it may not have been started if nothing is referencing it
- Can you see your component in the ACC. Start the ACC, and go to View Components by Path and navigate to were you think your component should be. Can you see it there? If so, it means that your properties file is OK.
- In the ACC, When you click on the puzzle-piece icon that represents your component, does it show it as being an instance of your class or as an instance of Object. If Object, it means that it cannot determine the class of the component
- In the ACC, double-click the component and try to start it. Keep looking at the server logs as you do so

This should help you get to the bottom of things.